# How to compute correlation matrix with Bigmemory objects in R?

Tags: r

I want to compute the correlation matrix between two bigmemory.matrices in R. The code I am using is the following:

```
m1 <- as.big.matrix(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
m2 <- as.big.matrix(matrix(runif(100), 10, 10))
cor(m1, m2) # Gives me Error
```

Comment: Type mismatch! The mode of m1 and m2 are "S4", but the mode of the arguments x and y in the function cor is "numeric vector", "matrix" or "data frame".

Comment: @TokhtaHorqin  do i need a different function?

Comment: I think you need write your function, whose mode of x and y is "S4".